get_next_line function got "time out" or "cannot be executed" in trace for Exam 03 at 42 SG
Is anyone able to think of any mistakes I could have made in the following code to get time out or cannot be executed in the traces for Exam 03 at 42 SG? I was sure I git pushed. (The code below works and passes the exam simulator at https://github.com/JCluzet/42_EXAM. But I am wondering what I could have done wrong during the exam on 30 Oct 2024 to get time out or cannot be executed in the traces for Exam 03 at 42 SG.)
The exam question at
https://github.com/JCluzet/42_EXAM/blob/main/.subjects/STUD_PART/exam_03/0/get_next_line/attachment/subject.en.txt (modified to allow get_next_line.h which is what I got during the exam on 30 Oct 2024):
Assignment name : get_next_line
Expected files : get_next_line.c and get_next_line.h
Allowed functions: read, free, malloc

Write a function named get_next_line which prototype should be:
char *get_next_line(int fd);
Your function must return a line that has been read from the file descriptor passed as parameter. What we call a "line that has been read" is a succession of 0 to n characters that end with '\n' (ascii code 0x0a) or with End Of File (EOF).
The line should be returned including the '\n' in case there is one at the end of the line that has been read. When you've reached the EOF, you must store the current buffer in a char * and return it. If the buffer is empty you must return NULL.
In case of error return NULL. In case of not returning NULL, the pointer should be free-able. Your program will be compiled with the flag -D BUFFER_SIZE=xx, which has to be used as the buffer size for the read calls in your functions.
Your function must be memory leak free. When you've reached the EOF, your function should keep 0 memory allocated with malloc, except the line that has been returned.
Calling your function get_next_line() in a loop will therefore allow you to read the text available on a file descriptor one line at a time until the end of the text, no matter the size of either the text or one of its lines.
Make sure that your function behaves well when it reads from a file, from the standard output, from a redirection, etc...
No call to another function will be done on the file descriptor between 2 calls of get_next_line(). Finally we consider that get_next_line() has an undefined behaviour when reading from a binary file.

My "get_next_line.h":
#ifndef GET_NEXT_LINE_H
# define GET_NEXT_LINE_H

# ifndef BUFFER_SIZE
#  define BUFFER_SIZE 10
# endif

# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

char *get_next_line(int fd);
#endif

My "get_next_line.c":
#include "get_next_line.h"

char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char b[99999999] = {'\0'};
    static int  i = 0;
    char        *l;
    int     r;
    int     f;

    r = 1;
    f = 0;
    while (r > 0)
    {
        r = read(fd, &b[f], BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (r < 0 || b[i] == '\0') //b[i] == '\0' is to detect the EOF (i.e. end of file).
            return (NULL);
        f += r;
    }
    r = 0;
    while (b[i + r] != '\0' && b[i + r] != '\n')
        r++;
    l = malloc(r + 1 + (b[i + r] == '\n'));
    if (!l)
        return (NULL);
    f = 0;
    while (f < r + (b[i + r] == '\n'))
        l[f++] = b[i++];
    l[f] = '\0';
    return (l);
}

Printscreen of the above code passing the exam simulator at https://github.com/JCluzet/42_EXAM:

My "main.c" to test:
#include "get_next_line.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     file;
    char    *next_line;

    file = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        while (1)
        {
            next_line = get_next_line(file);
            if (next_line == NULL)
                break ;
            printf("%s", next_line);
        }
    }
    close(file);
    return (1);
}

Printscreen of debugging for @Someprogrammerdude:


static char b[99999999] = {'\0'}; is a really bad idea. As is any use of static variables. That makes it hard to impossible to call the function multiple times. Not to mention that you waste a lot of space.

Also, who told you to use b[i] == '\0'? Where is the input coming from? Will the source of the input really send a string null-terminator? And why will it always be at b[0], especially since you might be way of into the buffer and nowhere near the first element of b?

As for the problem itself, you need to create a [mre], and debug your program. For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

@Someprogrammerdude. b[i] == '\0' is to detect the EOF (i.e. end of file).

@Someprogrammerdude. I've inserted a "main.c" (that I use for testing) at the end of my question above.

End of file is detected with r == 0.

@Someprogrammerdude. Maybe I should be more precise.
With static char b[99999999] = {'\0'}, every char in b is set to zero.
When the end of file is reached and nothing is read by read(fd, &b[f], BUFFER_SIZE);, r would be zero.
After every run of l[f++] = b[i++];, b[i] is thus '\0' because b[i - 1] is the last char being filled by read(fd, &b[f], BUFFER_SIZE);.

Static local variables are only initialized the first time the function is called. The next call it will not be initialized, it's contents will stay from the previous call.

@Someprogrammerdude. Pardon me but I don't see why the following that you wrote matters.
Static local variables are only initialized the first time the function is called. The next call it will not be initialized, it's contents will stay from the previous call.

Because if you first read "abcde", and the next call you read "fg", then the contents of b will be "fgcde". I recommend you use the same technique used by the standard C function fgets, which takes a pointer to a buffer, and its size, as arguments. That will simplify a lot for your function. Most importantly, it will avoid the need to do dynamic allocation and risk potential memory leaks.

@Someprogrammerdude. I assume that "abcde" is the first line in the file and "fg" is the 2nd line in the same file.
Assuming also that the file contains only these 2 lines, then b would be "abcde\nfg\0\0\0..." after the first call of the function get_next_line(). Because all lines in the file are read and stored into b in the first call although the writing to l is done in 2 calls -- one line per call -- "abcde\n" in the first call and "fg" in the 2nd call.

@Someprogrammerdude. Thanks for recommending fgets() and explaining how it works. But the exam question insists that the prototype should be:
char *get_next_line(int fd);
I think the school wants us to learn dynamic allocation and avoiding potential memory leaks.

You read into &b[f], and f always start out as 0. Each call start at the beginning of b. Please use a debugger to step through the code and see what actually happens.

The header should not include any other headers.  The function it declares takes an int argument and returns a char *; those types do not require any header to declare them.  Headers should be self-contained, idempotent, and minimal.  Yours is self-contained and idempotent, but it is not minimal.

You should (1) check that you opened the file successfully, and (2) only close the file if it is opened successfully.  If your test code isn't given a file to open, it closes standard input (which isn't a disaster in this context since the program exits immediately afterwards, but would not be good in any other context).  You should report when the program is misused (invoked with other than one argument — too many arguments are as bad as too few in my book), and should report the error on standard error.

What constitutes a "binary file"?  Is it a file that has a zero (null) byte in it, or is the definition more complex?  The exam question isn't clear; your code works on the assumption that a null byte is what matters (which is reasonable) but doesn't handle such data properly.  Do you have to worry about files encoded in UTF-16?  (Probably not!) I don't see where you reset i to zero — AFAICS, you won't be able to read safely from really big files.  The b[i] test will eventually read out of bounds of the static array.

@Someprogrammerdude. I've inserted a printscreen of debugging at the end of my question above.

First, please don't post images of text. Secondly, you forget to print out the value of r after the second time you call read. Thirdly, you don't call the function multiple times. Fourthly, the first call to get_next_line reads all of the file, leaving nothing for future calls. Assuming that the rest of the code works as intended (which is not clear at this point) you will read all of the contents and return a pointer to the first line, then the next call will return NULL.

@Someprogrammerdude. I see. Thanks for trying so much to help.
